# cannot fix in Safari: SyntaxError: Invalid character: '#' after upgrade to Angular 16

Tags: angular, safari, syntax-error, invalid-characters

I upgraded to Angular 16, i have upgraded packages and I get the following error in Safari: SyntaxError: Invalid character: '#'
My safari version is 14. In Chrome I do not get this error and the application opens.

See the package.json

```
{
  "name": "carpathia",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~16.0.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "~16.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~16.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~16.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "~16.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~16.0.4",
    "@angular/localize": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^16.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~16.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~16.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "~16.0.4",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.1",
    "stable": "^0.1.8",
    "tslib": "^2.5.3",
    "webpack": "^5.85.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.19",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~16.0.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "~16.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.2",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^20.2.5",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^4.0.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.9",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": ">=4.9.3 and <5.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.2"
  }
}
```

I tried to downgrade packages, changes different versions of Webpack, downgraded and upgraded Node and removed the custom styles but nothing worked. When I run npx browserslist I see that Safari 14 is not on the list and nothing worked to get it on the list.

Comment: I would encourage you to go through and check if the version numbers are compatible with Angular 9

Comment: Where does it say that error is coming from?  It's hard to take a guess at what would cause this without that information.  Your package file doesn't really give a lot of information about a runtime error in Safari.

Comment: @alin-lazar Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Angular only provides support to the last 2 [browser versions](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support). So, If you want to support older browsers, you need to create/update your .browserslistrc to include the browsers you want to support!

This is how I fixed this error by adding the following in the .browserslistrc file.

```
Chrome >=99 
Firefox >=99 
Edge >=79 
Safari >=13 
iOS >=13
```

Answer (score 0):

Safari 14 doesn't support private methods https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_classes_private_class_methods

So you need to polyfill with babel or downgrade back

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by using browserslist. Make sure you have safari 14 in the browserslist query by running "npx browserslist". I changed from `last 2 versions` to `last 3 major versions`